# Adding new entity to existing data model causes the users data to disappear (lightweight Core Data migration doesn't work)

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, core-data-migration

I've got my app in the App Store with datamodel in version 2. I created version 3 of the data model, set it as current and add 1 new entity to it (attributes are marked as Optional). This new entity has no relations with others. Of course NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption and NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption are both set to YES. Now if I overwrite the app downloaded from the App Store (with datamodel v2) by Xcode version (with datamodel v3), users data is missing. There is no information in the log about any problem.

I have searched on Stack Overflow for the solution for hours and (I think) tried everything (e.g. delete and re-add the xcdatamodel file in version 1, then create version 2 and 3 of the data model) but haven't found any solution.

I would like to add that I have done similar changes (added new entity) in my other app and everything works perfectly - users data is migrated using lightweight method to new version of data model.

Please help :)